# How to install gcc 3.2?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc

I need to use gcc 3.2. No prior answers exactly resolved this problem. It looks like this version is not available in a apt-get repository and I do not exactly know how to install it using the source in later gcc versions.

Is there a way to install gcc 3.2 in any version of ubuntu?

Comment: Did you check here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.2/

Comment: `gcc` 3.2 was released 2002, and replaced with 3.3 in 2003 ; so you're talking about a REALLY old version of `gcc`  (https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)   Most modern code won't use anything from that old (a `gcc` that was out-of-date when Ubuntu started in 2004).

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! I guess compiling from sources is the only option for such an old and outdated piece of software.

Comment: I know this is very old. But I need this for some experiments. I tried the source but failing due to some incompatibility with the current gcc. I tried installing with gcc 3.3 and gcc 2.95 but didn't do any good.

Comment: What were the error messages when building? Please [edit] your question to include them. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.